# The use of indexes on queries against linked servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was reading a blog today and ran across this comment.

> When executing a query on a remote linked server, even if it is SQL Server, the query plan cannot take advantage of indexes or statistics to find the best way to resolve your query.

I have spent some time researching this issue but I can not find a clear answer to this.  Anybody have any insight??

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Well the specific question would be if I wrote a query that included a a table connected by a linked server with an INNER JOIN on the PRIMARY KEYs on each table, will the linked table have to do a full table scan to implement the derived table on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly right. Even if you join on a table it has to pull the whole table back, and then filter on what your join criteria is.

If you are needing to do lots of joining and mixing of data using linked servers, you aren't thinking in terms of SQL Server best practices.

Maybe edit your question to better reflect what is is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The long and the short of it is that the stored procedures to get table statistics on the remote side require elevated permissions (at least ddl_admin) to run. If the principal on the remote side doesn't have those permissions, the optimizer assumes that 1 row will come back from that table and builds a plan based on that.

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.spartansql.com/2012/10/cardinality-estimates-over-linked-server.html) that shows a way to get around this without needing elevated permissions.

Comment: Ironically, given the name of blog post,  I am posting from Spartanburg, SC from a organization with 'Spartan' in the name.

It's an interesting approach but I am working in a organization that doesn't handle exception very well.